# In JavaScript, if a condition is always true, is it necessary to check?

Tags: javascript

I understand what this is doing, and it is behaving as expected, but is the following JavaScript conditional statement even necessary?

`if(true) { ...code here }`

This will always resolve to true and run the code within, so why even have it?

I'm code reviewing a .js file for a colleague and questioning whether or not this is necessary.  The statement indeed resolves to true and runs the code within. Without the condition it also runs the code, so why check an absolute truthy condition?

Comment: You can remove the if statement. It's not needed if that's the case

Comment: That is not necessary, no. Probably a remnant of some code refactoring / changing requirements or something like that.

Comment: An open lock left on an open gate :-)

Comment: what is true? or `if(true)` is all you have in your condition?

Comment: Yea you need to clarify whether the code is **literally** `if (true)` or if it's an expression that you think will always be true.

Comment: Note that removing the condition can change the scope of the variables inside it. You may want to leave the curlies to make a block. But you can ditch the condition.

Comment: It might be a poor man's mechanism to manually disable a code block during debugging. If your colleague hasn't left for greener pastures, just ask him.

Comment: Possibly it was from a server generated javascript.
For example `if (<?= $someServerCondition ? "true" : "false" ?>)`

Comment: this is a useful technique when developing or debugging code. It is normally planned to remove them once the code has been validated

Comment: @ChrisG - The condition is literally just `if(true)`

Comment: @midasxl in that case it's probably an artifact of something else as the comments suggested. Only the person who wrote it could tell you for sure. But other than set up a block scope it doesn't do anything, and you can have a block with just the curlies as I said before, meaning the condition is entirely superfluous.